# PHP/Mysql Database populated dropdown list spitting out index number instead of string value

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why my drop down list, which is populated from Mysql, is giving me a number instead of the string value. Below is the code for the drop down list, which properly displays the item names.  The problem is when I pull the selected item later I get a number instead of the string item name the user selected.

```
<select name="product1" class="form-control" id="sel1">
<?php
    require('./PHPConnect.php');

    $dropdown = array();
    $downquery = "SELECT * FROM  masterDESC";

    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $downquery);

    if($response){
        while(($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQL_ASSOC))){
            $dropdown[] = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
        }
    }

    foreach($dropdown as $key => $value){
        echo '<option value=' . $key . '>' . $value . '</option>';
    }

    echo "</select>";
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Here is the code later used to pull the selected item.

```
$product1 = $_POST['product1'];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I got it figured out.  It was the key value pair on the foreach.  It was necessary for a similar drop down I created in the past but didn't work here.  I just got rid of the foreach and it worked.

```
<select name="product1" class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <?php
                        require('./PHPConnect.php');

                        //$dropdown = array();

                        $downquery = "SELECT * 
                                FROM  masterDESC";

                        $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $downquery);

                        if($response){
                            while(($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQL_ASSOC))){
                                $dropdown = "<option value=\"{$row['DESCRIPTION']}\">
                                {$row['DESCRIPTION']}</option>\n";
                                echo $dropdown;
                            }
                        }

                        echo "</select>";
                        mysqli_close($dbc);
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is spitting put the index number because you are retrieving an array which is just the description values (from this "$dropdown[] = $row['DESCRIPTION'];" you have returned from the DB and when there are no keys listed - the array index is the $key - therefore the number

you need to change the following

```
foreach($dropdown as $key => $value){
    echo '<option value=' . $key . '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

to this and set the value of the option to the same as the displayed content (or leave it with the number and reference it later as $dropdown[index].

```
foreach($dropdown as $value){
    echo '<option value="' . $value. '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
```